# How to set value of select in material UI from nested menu item (react)

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have a Select component from material-ui, but I can't set the value of nested items, how can I set the value of clicked nested menu items to the parent select?

```
const [anchorEl, setAnchorEl] = React.useState(null);
  const open = Boolean(anchorEl);

  const handleClick = (event) => {
    return setAnchorEl(event.currentTarget);
  };
  const handleClose = () => setAnchorEl(null);

  return (
    <Select
    onOpen={handleClick}
    onClose={handleClose}
    onChange={e => {
      console.log('changed: ', e.target.value)
    }}>
      <MenuItem
      value={'menu-item-1'}>
        Menu Item 1
      </MenuItem>
      <MenuItem
      value={'menu-item-2'}>
        Menu Item 2
      </MenuItem>
      <NestedMenuItem label={"Go deeper!"} parentMenuOpen={open}>
        <MenuItem 
        value={'sub-menu-item'}
        onClick={handleClose}>Sub-menu item
        </MenuItem>
      </NestedMenuItem>
    </Select>
  );
```

this is a demo from the Select with NestedMenuItems
https://codesandbox.io/s/react-nested-select-zxxejy?file=/src/App.js